# Printing a dictionary without newlines?

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io, printing, formatting

I'm trying to get the formatting right on my print-out and it's trickier than it should be. My objective is to have my code read in a dictionary, turn it to a list, sort it, then print it back out a text file looking like

"String" "Float"

"String" "Float"

"String" "Float"

When instead it prints

string

float

string

float

Looking at the raw data that is my dictionary it looks like:

```
{'blahblah\n': 0.3033367037411527, 'barfbarf\n': 0.9703779366700716,
```

I suspect the \n newline command has something to do with this. But I can't seem to mitigate it. My code is as follows:

```
#Open the text file and read it back it
h = open('File1.txt', 'r')
my_dict = eval(h.read())

#Print out the dictionary
print "Now tidying up the data......"
z = my_dict

#Turn the dictionary into a list and print it
j = open('File2.txt', 'w')
z = z.items()
z.sort(key=lambda t:t[1])
z.reverse()
for user in z:
    print >> j, user[0], user[1]
j.close()
```

This code works perfectly in just about every other part of my program. For some reason it's having issues here.

Comment: Try [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Comment: The `\n` certainly has something to do with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\n` is a newline character. Written to a file it shows as a line break. You should remove it before printing out:

```
print >> j, user[0].strip(), user[1].strip()
```

Or even better, do it while turning to a list:

```
z = [item.strip() for item in z.items()]
```

Comment: Looks like I only need the .strip() on the string and not the float. Thanks for the answer!